# add unique name to radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that will grab some html and repeat it with each time "add product" is clicked. I got this to work seemingly well, but I realized that multiple products (the same product) can be added. Thus, the radio buttons interfere. They would need unique radio name attributes. I don't even know where to start by doing this, I suppose I could have a counter and add it to the current name... Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is an example of the html:

```
<div id="product-container" class="product-container" style="display:none">
<div class="product-wrapper white-rounded">
    <div id="product-name" style="display:none"></div>
        <h4>Example Product 1</h4>
        <span class="align-right">
            <input name="select2" type="radio"><strong style="margin-right:20px">Option 1</strong>
            <input name="select2" type="radio"><strong>Option 2</strong>
        </span>
        <div class="remove float-right">
           <a href="#"><div class="img-remove"></div>Remove</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

   </div>
</div>
```

And, here is the jQuery that grabs the code and spits it out at an anchor point:

```
$('.add-product').click(function() {
        if (Products < 4 || (Products == 4 && Products2 == 1)) {
        //Store html contents in Variable
            var thisProduct = $('#product-container').html()
        //Add account html to account center anchor point
            $('.add-product').before(thisProduct)
            $('#product-name').text(productName)
        //Add one more Product Count
            Products++
        //Add Product Count value to hidden Input Field, then manually trigger the change event.
            $('.product-count').val(Products).change()
        //Scroll to top of page after account is added
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        }

        else {
            alert('HALP!');
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like your code is duplicating IDs as well and that's a no-no.

Comment: Well, it grabs the html inside of the container with the ID, and doesn't repeat it in the actual markup. At least I don't think so... but I will double check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do an increment to the name?

This way it will never repeat the same name!

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking, I am just not super-awesome with jQuery and am unsure on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest was to solve this is to just have a count running and append that to your id or class, that way it will allways be unique

```
    var un1 = 0;

for(yourloop){
    $("#whatever").append("idname"+un1);
    un1++;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I would have to append 'un1' to the name="whatever" field.

I am probably explaining this terribly. When I add this html content more then once, and I select a radio button it will deselect all the other radio buttons. So, I need to change the name field to make them all unique.